# Is there a way to catch the logs from Sentry and post them to my custom Backend?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, error-handling, sentry

I integrated **Sentry** into my **Angular** Application.

Is there a way to catch the logs from Sentry and send them to a customized endpoint?

The target is to combine the Sentry Dashboard but also with my Backend (built with Java Springboot)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using beforeSend

```
Sentry.init({
  ...
 
  beforeSend(event) {
    // Send here 
    fetch('https://yourwebsite.com/someapi', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(event)})
    return event;
  },
});
```